# Angular. Ambiguous $watch behavior for sync and async code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I have an [`exapmle`](http://jsfiddle.net/night_skylark/Byca5/5/) where value for watched variable can be set in current stack or can be loaded asynchronously (it is incapsulated code). So, i can not be sure, if the value was changed, when the watch handler called.

I have read and understand [this API description](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), but i still don`t know, how to fix my code.

PS: I was trying to call `$scope.$digest()`, but $apply was already in progress.

Comment: The watcher fires as it should. What is your problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it fires the hadler asynchronously, so if my flag 'async' equals to false, then oldValue equals to newValue, thus I am not sure, should I call repaint() (see my fiddle).

Comment: Not clear what behaviour your are expecting

Comment: I want to call repaint() method each time when value of 'text' variable was changed, and only those times independently of moment when value was changed (sync or async).

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to fire the $watch function you need to change the value of the "Text". here is a

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Byca5/6/)

Code snippet:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" />
```

Comment: It does not fix my problem. I want to call repaint() method each time when value of 'text' variable was changed, and only those times independently of moment when value was changed (sync or async).

Comment: Did not get you...I put an alert in the repaint function, it is getting called on each change caught by watch. here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Byca5/8/

Comment: This alert calls form line 6 of code, not from watcher, and value changes after it by method loadData. Watch handler called, but comparing (newValue !== oldValue) returns false. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/night_skylark/Byca5/9/

Comment: I changed the alert function to compare newValue with the oldValue and whenever the text is changed in Custom textbox it appears as true....fiddler:http://jsfiddle.net/Byca5/10/

Comment: Textbox does not use my watcher. I need to make my own repaint. Your binding is not interesting for me. It does not resolve my task.

Comment: Text box is using scope variable text in ngModel, it is not agreeable that it is not using the watcher as whenever I am typing in textbox it is firing the watcher function.

Answer (score 0):

Your watch function will be called whenever `$scope.$digest` is called (this is called by $apply function ). `$digest` is called for **browser events** (click, keydown.. ),**$http** request completed, and also by **$timeouts**.

I think you need to use $timeout service here instead of setTimeout

```
  $timeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve('test value');

        }, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Byca5/7/ . This will fire $scope.$apply for you after timeout completed.

When `async = false` your value will set immediately when the controller is loaded or when the $scope is created. So when first $digest cycle happens there is no change in the $scope.text. That's why it newVal==oldvalue.

Comment: setTimeout is only for example. It can be a request to DB server.

Comment: I understand your explanation about the reason of this behavior, this is an angularjs philosofy. But i still cannot understand how to resolve my task.